# Laravel controller not responding back on AJAX request

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i am typing text in text area

```
 <input placeholder="DISCOUNT COUPON" type="text" id="coupon">
```

Sending that text to controller using ajax;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "applyCoupon",      
    data:{
    coupon: $('#coupon').val(),
    course_id: {{$course->id}},
    _token: {{ csrf_token() }},
    },
    success: function(dataResult){
    alert("success");} // why i am not GETTING this alert?
```

**Controller:**

```
public function applyCoupon(Request $request)
    {
        $result=new \stdClass();
        $coupons = Coupons::select('discount_percentage')->where('coupon_code',$request->get('coupon'))
                            ->where('course_id',$request->get('course_id'))
                            ->get();
        $course = Course::findOrFail($request->get('course_id'));
        $discounted_price=  ($course->price) - (($course->price)*($coupons[0]->discount_percentage)/100);

        $result->val = $discounted_price;
        $result->statusCode = 200;
        return json_encode($result);

    }
```

**Web.php:**

```
Route::post('course/applyCoupon', ['uses' => 'CoursesController@applyCoupon', 'as' => 'courses.applyCoupon']);
```

**everything seems fine, but why success function is not running?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `routes/api.php` instead of `routes/web.php`in the first place.

Also, log error by adding

```
...
    error: function (request, error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Error");
    },
```

That should give you a clue. Could be anything depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the full URL you setup in your `routes/web.php`

Change

```
url: "applyCoupon",
```

to

```
 url: "course/applyCoupon",
```

or even better would be to use the route name you provided

```
 url: "{{route('courses.applyCoupon')}}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Give correct route to your ajax call

Pass this in your ajax url.

```html
url: "{{ route('courses.applyCoupon' }}"
```

if still not working, then Check your network tab in inspect tool
[image]

Click on the ajax call and it will show you the detail on your right side.
post here what you are getting there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the response in return of ajax call:-

```
use Response;

return response()->json(['message' => 'error', 'data' => $data]);
```